# What is the most accurate way to determine the amount of water in a material from XRF and LOD-105 results?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, materials, mixtures, elemental-analysis, composition

this might seem like a silly question but I want to be sure. I have the results from an external laboratory for the bulk chemical composition (by XRF) and moisture (by Loss on Drying to 105 degrees Celsius) (among other test parameters, PSD etc.) and I'm wondering what the most accurate way is to incorporate the amount of water into subsequent equations I'm using for a mathematical model.

For example, let's assume I have 1 g of the material with 50 wt.% Si and 50 wt.% Al (as an example) from its XRF data and 1.5% (or 1.5 g H2O / g Sample) moisture from the Loss on Drying method results. Which of the following methods below (or a different method) is better for quantifying the amount of water in the material better? Please provide a detailed and reasoned response.

$\textbf{Method 1:}\\
1 \text{ g Sample} \times 1.5 \text{ g H}_2\text{O} / \text{g sample} = 0.015 \text{ g H}_2\text{O}$

$\textbf{Method 2:}\\
1 \text{ g Sample} = X \text{ g Solids} + Y \text{ g Liquids} = X \text{ g Solids} + Y \text{ g H}_2\text{O} = 100\text{wt.% Solids} + 1.5 \text{ wt.% Liquids} = 101.5 \text{ wt.% Sample}\\
\text{Therefore: } Y \text{ g Liquids} = 1 \text{ g Sample} \times \left(\frac{1.5 \text{ wt% Liquids}}{101.5 \text{ wt% Sample}}\right) = 0.0148 \text{ g H}_2\text{O}$

Note that with this example the moisture % is small, and both methods produce a similar result, but with other samples the moisture % may be bigger and thus introduce more errors if I have the calculations wrong, so I want to be sure I'm doing things right.